# Error creating instance of object in a function

Tags: python

Why am I not able to create a new instance of `mySecondClass`?

I get this error:

```
NameError: global name 'mySecondClass' is not defined
```

`mySecondClass.py`

```
class mySecondClass(myBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        #Do something
```

`mainApp.py`

```
class MainApp(object):

    def __init__(self):
        #Do something
        self.create_x(self)


    def create_x(self):
        n = mySecondClass() # error here!!!!! why?

        print 'created'


mainApp()
```

Comment: Did you `import mySecondClass`?

Answer (score 0):

Each `.py` file is a module. For a module to access another module's content, it needs to import it first.

In your case, you need to `import mySecondClass`:

```
from mySecondClass import mySecondClass

x = mySecondClass()
```

or

```
import mySecondClass

x = mySecondClass.mySecondClass()
```

Read more about modules at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. is that because that class is in a different file?

Comment: Yes, each file is a module that needs to be imported by other modules to access its contents

Comment: so is the import name actually the file name?   So if the file was myTest.py, then I would import myTest

Comment: @Sir_FZ please add your explanation (from the comments) to the actual answer

Comment: Edited my answer to make things clearer. And yes, the name of the module is the name of its file/directory. Read more at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html